# storing button click in local storage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, stringify

I'm trying to store button clicks in local storage, so when user clicks the button, the date and time the user clicks it will be stored in local storage. However at the moment the data gets overwritten by new dates when I close the window, opens again and click the button the second time. What I want is for the local storage to store every single button click without overwriting past data. I heard JSON stringify should do the job but its not working.

```
    function saveData(){
        var date= new Date();
        window.localStorage.setItem("date", JSON.stringify(date));  
        alert("Your data is stored");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use an array for that

```
function saveData(){
    var data  = localStorage.getItem("date");

    var dates = data ? JSON.parse(data) : [];

    dates.push( Date.now() );

    localStorage.setItem("date", JSON.stringify(dates));  

    alert("Your data is stored");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. After integrating your code, for some reason no dates were saved into local storage at all. And the alert is not showing after I clicked the button either

Comment: hmm, could it be because I'm using PhoneGap for iOS and it doesn't support some of the functions? Because I've basically copy and pasted your jsfiddle code to see if it works in my app simulator, and it still doesn't

Comment: I think it might be something to do with using jquery with phonegap. I'll start a new question and ask around. Thanks a lot for the help though!

Comment: localStorage should work with PhoneGap, so not sure what the issue might be ?

Comment: I'm assuming might be due to the jQuery version or something? Because my original code was not written with jQuery, just javascript.

Comment: @michelle9090 did YOU get the solution to the problem?